# javascript; What is the difference between two pieces of codes below

Tags: javascript

I am trying to understand how are these two pieces of code different.

```
var bill=10.25+3.99+7.15;
var tip = bill*0.15;
var total=bill+tip;
total = total.toFixed(2);
console.log("$"+total);
```

And

```
var bill=10.25+3.99+7.15;
var tip = bill*0.15;
var total=bill+tip;
console.log("$"+total.toFixed(2));
```

Comment: They aren't in any substantial sense.

Comment: One of them updates the `total` variable before outputting it.  The other does not.

Comment: Why do you think, they are different? They’re all the same, as is `console.log("$" + ((10.25 + 3.99 + 7.15) * 1.15).toFixed(2));`.

Answer (score 1):

Explanation in comments:

```
   <script>
     var bill=10.25+3.99+7.15;
     var tip = bill*0.15; 
     var total=bill+tip; // total is number
     total = total.toFixed(2); // total has been converted into a string with only two decimal places
     console.log("$"+total); //prints out the '$' along with value of total variable which is a 'string'
     typeof total; //returns "string"
   </script>
```

---

```
    <script>
       var bill=10.25+3.99+7.15;
       var tip = bill*0.15;
       var total=bill+tip; //total is number
       console.log("$"+total.toFixed(2)); //even after this statement the type of 'total' is integer, as no changes were registered to 'total' variable.
       typeof total; //returns "number"
    </script>
```